# Binding objects to a checkbox

Tags: cocoa-bindings

Really simple binding question.  I have a checkbox on my MainMenu.xib, and I also have a text field and a date picker.  I want to bind the hidden attribute of the field/picker to the checkbox such that if the box is checked the date picker is *not* hidden, and the text field is hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do the following:

Checkbox    -> Bind `Value` to your boolean.

Text Field  -> Bind `Hidden` to same boolean.

Date Picker -> Bind `Hidden` to same boolean. Set its `Value Transformer` to `NSNegateBoolean`.

Here's a github project you can checkout for an example (everything is in the xib). https://github.com/macandyp/CocoaCheckBoxBindings